# Append End of Line with Substring from Current Line

Tags: regex, append, substring, notepad++, eol

I've scoured Stack Overflow for something just like this and can't seem to come up with a solution. I've got some text that looks like this:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@Id
command.Parameters.Add("@IsDeleted
command.Parameters.Add("@MasterRecordId
command.Parameters.Add("@Name
...
```

And I would like the text to end up like this:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@Id", acct.Id);
command.Parameters.Add("@IsDeleted", acct.IsDeleted);
command.Parameters.Add("@MasterRecordId", acct.MasterRecordId);
command.Parameters.Add("@Name", acct.Name);
...
```

As you can see, I essentially want to append the end of the line with: ", acct.<word between @ and second ">);

I'm trying this:

Find What: `(?<=@).+?(?=\r)` - This works, it finds the appropriate word.

Replace: `\1", acct.\1);` - This doesn't. It changes the line to (for Id):

```
command.Parameters.Add("@", acct.
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I thought that `\1` is supposed to be the "capture" from the "Find what" box, but it's not I guess?

Answer (score 3):

The `\1` backreference will only work if you have a capturing group in your pattern:

```
(?<=@)(.+?)(?=\r)
```

If you're not using a capturing group, you should use `$&` instead of `\1` as a backreference for the entire match. Additionally, parentheses in the replacement string need to be escaped. So, the replacement string should be:

```
$&", acct.$&\);
```

You might also want to use `$` instead of the Lookahead `(?=\r)` in case the last line isn't followed by an EOL character.

Having said all that, I personally prefer to be more explicit/strict when doing regex substitution to avoid messing up other lines (i.e., false positives). So I would go with something like this:

Find: `(\bcommand\.Parameters\.Add\("@)(\w+)$`

Replace: `\1\2", acct.\2\);`

Note that `\w` will only match word characters, which is likely the desired behavior here. Feel free to replace it with a character class if you think your identifiers might have other characters.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! And thanks for the explanations, I only need to do something like this once in a great while and I always have a difficult time because the cheat sheets I've found don't go in depth enough.

Answer (score 1):

You could also omit the lookbehind, and match the @ and then use `\K` to clear the current match buffer.

Then you can match the rest of the line using `.+`

*Note that you don't have to make the quantifier non greedy `.*?` as you are matching the rest of the line.*

In the replacement, use the full match using `$0`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tx5HXv/1) for the matches:

**Find what:**

```
@\K.+
```

**Replace with:**

```
$0", acct.$0\)
```

[image]

---

If there must be a newline to the right, you might also write the pattern as one of:

```
@\K.+(?=\r)
@\K.+(?=\R)
```